# Data file only saves 12 rows when loc is used to sort database

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I am trying to iteratively select the 500 rows and all columns using `.loc` in pandas. However, the final written file only shows data up to 12 rows of data. First 5 rows and last 5 rows. **Middle data is not displayed on the written file. What needs to be done to display all 500 rows ???**

Following is code

```
"""
Program to 
1. load data from a file. Skip the first 52 rows of data from a tab-separated file. 
2. Select 500 rows and all columns from the dataset. Write this file. 
3. Use the next name for saving the next set of 500 rows and iterate this process for 20 times

"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime
import shutil
import math
import datetime

b='b'
b=pd.read_csv('Oct4_3.dat',delimiter='\t',skiprows=52)
c=0
d=500


for i in range (1,20):
    a='a'
    filename = 'a'+str(i)+'.dat'
        
    a=a+str(i)
    print(a)    

    a=b.loc[c:d,'# V UG']   

    f = open(filename,'a+')    
    f.write(" %s \n"%(a))
    c=d+1
    d=d+500
    f.close()
   
print('done')
```

output of code generates 20 files. One specific file looks like following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you get in your file seem like the result of the `print(a)`.
To save a pandas dataframe as a csv, use `to_csv()` method

```
a.to_csv('your_csv_filename.csv',index=False)
```

Also, you are saving 501 rows for the first iteration and not 500 (index start at 0 not 1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to save all 501 rows with "a.to_csv(filename,index=False)" as you mentioned. Also deleated unwanted file opening and closing parts from the code.